# Strange navigation transition behavior with SwiftUI async / await loading screen

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, async-await, navigation

When launching the app, I need to fire an async process to setup a DB. The idea is that meanwhile this is happening, a loading screen is shown, and once it completes the app proceeds to the main UI.

```
struct MyApp: App {
    enum UIState {
        case loading, main
    }
    @State var state = UIState.loading
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            switch state {
            case .loading:
                Text("loading...")
                  .task {
                      await Services.current.db.start()
                      state = .main
                  }
            case .main:
                MyContentView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MyContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("next view")) {
                Text("lets go!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This seemingly works as expected: the launch screen is shown, and then the MyContentView.

However, the navigation transition animation is missing when tapping the NavigationLink. What is weirder that it is always the first one missing, if it's a chain of views, all push animations plays how they are supposed to, except for the first one (pop animations work for all cases).

Now, if I remove everything, and in the WindowGroup there is only MyContentView of course navigation animations are working perfectly.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Works fine here (at least with stubbed async service). Xcode 13.2 / iOS 15.2

Comment: Yes, works fine here as well. Check again but replace the `await Services.current.db.start()` with a simple `sleep(3)`.

Comment: Did you try to put the navigation view over the case ?

Comment: Thank you, I have changed the ```Services.current.db.start()``` to ```do { try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 3_000_000_000) } catch { }``` I am observing the same behavior. iOS 15.2 simulator and device both, XCode 13.2.1

Comment: @PtitXav your suggestion works. However this means I have to reorganize views, and it makes this whole case even more strange. I really appreciate your comment. Any ideas why it works?

Comment: I think that the navigation needs to be there before the navigation link appears. Animation show only things that are done: if creating navigation view and navigation link at same time, this result on displaying navigation link after it appears in navigation link = after navigation animation. Look at Stanfords cs193p lectures 6,7,8 of spring 2021 : there is a lot of explanation about this.

Comment: Hmm, but in the original example the NavigationLink is already embedded in the navigation view. I would think due to to view composability there is no difference in the view is embedded inside a navigation view, or the contents of the view are.